# How to find all the available tools in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I am trying to setup a bunch of development projects in my Mac. I have to run various tools like python, ruby, scala, groovy etc. 
To see if a tool is available I use options like

```
ruby --version.
```

Instead I would like to see all the list of tools available in Mac terminal via a single command. What is the command/options for it?

Comment: The list will be more overwhelming than informative. On macOS 10.14.4, I see 1,302 executables in /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, and /usr/sbin. Most of them obscure and/or single-purpose. For instance: `hpftodit`, which converts fonts from HP tagged font metric (TFM) format for  use  with  an HP Laser-Jet 4-series (or newer) printer with `groff -Tlj4`. Ok, that's an extreme example, I claim the point is still valid.

Answer (score 26):

The easiest is simply to open the Terminal and then press the TAB key twice. You'll be asked if you want to see all possibilities - reply "y" and you'll get the full list.

Answer (score 21):

See the answers from this U&L Q&A titled: 
 [List all commands that a shell knows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94775/list-all-commands-that-a-shell-knows)
.

My personal favorite is to utilize `compgen` since this is part of the family of tools used to build all the tab completion when you're in a terminal and hit <kbd>tab></kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> twice.

```
$ compgen -c
```

#### Example

```
$ compgen -c | tail
deepcopy-gen
kube-controller-manager
informer-gen
lister-gen
etcd
gen-apidocs
kube-apiserver
kubectl
kubebuilder
conversion-gen
```

Incidentally, if you want to know where one of these executables lives on your HDD use `type -a <cmd>` to find it:

```
$ type -a ansible
ansible is aliased to `ANSIBLE_CONFIG=~/.ansible.cfg ansible'
ansible is /usr/local/bin/ansible
```

This shows that the command `ansible` is an alias and also lives locally on the HDD here: `/usr/local/bin/ansible`.

#### References

- [8.7 Programmable Completion Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html)

Answer (score 5):

You could take the PATH variable and `tr`anslate the colons into spaces then list the files in those directories.

```
ls  $(tr ':' ' ' <<<"$PATH")
```

And as Peter Cordes points out, the above will break if directory paths have spaces in their name. In a subshell, change the IFS (Internal Field Separator) to only a newline and `tr`anslate the colons to newlines.

```
( IFS=$'\n'; ls  $(tr ':' '\n' <<<"$PATH") )
```

Comment: If your `$PATH` contains spaces but not newlines, you can tr spaces to newlines inside an `(IFS=$'\n'; ls $(...))` subshell so word-splitting only happens on newline.

Answer (score 4):

When a command is installed, an entry should have been placed in the `whatis` database. However, there is no requirement to do so. To get a one line description of a command in the database, enter `whatis` followed by the command. For example, the output from entering `whatis "ruby"` is shown below.

```
erb(1)                   - Ruby Templating
irb(1)                   - Interactive Ruby Shell
ri(1)                    - Ruby API reference front end
ruby(1)                  - Interpreted object-oriented scripting language
```

This the `whatis` command will accept regular expressions. Therefore, to get a list of all commands in the database, enter the command given below.

```
whatis "."
```

The man page for `whatis` states the following:

> whatis  searches  a  set of database files containing short descriptions of system commands for keywords and displays the result on the standard output.  Only complete word matches are displayed.

There also exists a similar command called `apropos`. The man page for `apropos` states the following:

> apropos searches a set of database files containing short descriptions of system commands for keywords and displays the result on the standard output.

Basically, the difference is `apropos` does not require complete word matches. For example, `whatis "string"` would not find a match when encountering `strings`, but `apropos "string"` would.

Answer (score 1):

Seconding what @jksoegaard already mentioned, the simplest way is to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocompletion feature in Bash. Hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice lists all available shell internal commands, external commands and alias available. If you enter the initial characters of a command, the matching commands are listed when hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice.

There are 3rd party package managers available for macOS which lets you install command-line-tools which are either unavailable in the native installation of macOS, or have their older version installed. A couple popular package managers among software developers are [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org).

Thus, if you are interested in the broader spectrum of developer tools available to run on your Mac, you can also list all the command-line-tools available for easy installation and running by executing `brew search` for Homebrew and `port search` for MacPorts. Executing the said commands require the respective package managers to be installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness's sake, if you use `zsh`, you can use `ls "${(@)path}(N)"`. To get a list grouped by directory, use `ls "${(@)path}"/*(-*N)` or `printf "%s\n" "${(@)path}"/*(-*N)` (unsorted but in the order they would be found); `printf "%s\n" "${(@)path}"/*(-*N) | xargs -L 1 basename | sort -u` will give you a list of just the commands without paths.

Do note that this only shows executables, not aliases or functions. To get those, use `alias` or `typeset -f + | grep -v '^_'` respectively.

Sample output of each:

```
% ls "${(@)path}"(N)
/bin:
[         cat       cp
[...]
 sync      test      wait4path

/sbin:
apfs_hfs_convert fsck             fstyp
[...]
```

```
% ls "${(@)path}"/*(-*N)
/bin/[                                                      /usr/bin/nc                                                 /usr/local/bin/gmktemp
/bin/bash                                                   /usr/bin/ncal                                               /usr/local/bin/gmv
/bin/cat                                                    /usr/bin/ncctl                                              /usr/local/bin/gnice
/bin/chmod                                                  /usr/bin/ncdestroy                                          /usr/local/bin/gnl
/bin/cp                                                     /usr/bin/ncinit                                             /usr/local/bin/gnohup
/bin/csh                                                    /usr/bin/nclist                                             /usr/local/bin/gnproc
```

```
% printf "%s\n" "${(@)path}"/*(-*N)
/usr/local/bin/2to3
/usr/local/bin/2to3-2
/usr/local/bin/2to3-2.7
[...]
/usr/sbin/AppleFileServer
/usr/sbin/BootCacheControl
/usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity
/usr/sbin/DirectoryService
[...]
```

```
% printf "%s\n" "${(@)path}"/*(-*N) | xargs -L 1 basename | sort -u
2to3
2to3-
2to3-2
2to3-2.7
2to3-3.7
7z
7za
7zr
AppleFileServer
AssetCacheLocatorUtil
AssetCacheManagerUtil
[...]
znew
zprint
zsh
zsh-5.7.1
```